# Why having an id parameter in URI when updating a resource?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee

I am creating an API and I wonder why it is common to have a id parameter in URI for PUT?

Such as `PUT /cars/5`
Why don't have `PUT /cars`? The request entity contains an id field isn't that enough? I can get the id from that entity, or is it some downsides to this, and is it considered bad to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if you were to send a `PUT` request to `/cars`, semantically that would imply you are trying to modify attributes about *the set of cars*, rather than modifying attributes of *an individual car*. The URI in a RESTful API should indicate the exact resource the action is acting upon, so if you are modifying a resource, your URI should exactly indicate that resource.

Also, from [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6):

> The URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource.

So the spec indicates that if the client knows the resource's unique ID, it should be included in the URI.

Answer (score 2):

this comes from [rest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST_API) "ideology".

the idea is that a url uniquely represents an entity - so you must PUT the entity youre creating/editing to the url of that entity.

to quote from the wikipedia page:

> **Identification of resources**
>
> Individual resources are identified in requests, for example using URIs in web-based REST systems. The resources themselves are conceptually separate from the representations that are returned to the client.

Answer (score 2):

`PUT` aims to udpate ONE precised entity.

With merely using `/cars`, you aren't focus on a specific entity.

And on the contrary of what you wrote, your full entity isn't passed in a basic String (URI).

Excepted if your targeted method focus on a hard-coded `car` `id` ... but I don't think so..

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to the API interface. There are several approaches to API design. And, like you suggested, you can leave the id out of the request. However, since many API designs are structured in a fashion you described, like PUT /cars/5, it`s considered good practise.

Basically, you have 8 ways to interact with your API. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and an optional HEAD. ( if you count head, the total would be 9 or 10, depending on the interactions).

So, to clear it up, you have 2 ways of GET.  GET /cars would retrieve all cars, GET /cars/5 would retrieve any car with an ID of 5.So, you have 2 ways of using GET. The same goes for POST, PUT and DELETE. 4*2 = 8 right?

Now, there are people who would say that PUT /cars would be ambigious, however you are completely valid in doing it without the extra ID field, because, as you mentioned, you are already passing in the ID field in the request.

The guys at Apigee have been researching API designs for a while now. I recommend watching some of their video`s to understand better what API design means and why some arguments are valid, and others are not.

[Apigee Best practises](http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices)